# Is there something I can "release" to make this faster?

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, powerpoint

So this code will run through every chart I have in a presentation and look to do a Find/Replace on the values inside.

My presentations usually have 100-300 charts on them, and by the time the code gets to the 300th chart in the presentation, it takes 10-30 seconds to do everything (when it would do 5 graphs in that time when I initially run the program.)

So my question is: Is there any way to make this faster? I'm thinking something along the lines of "releasing" something from memory, if VBA has it, would be the solution but I can't find anything on that.

I added

```
    Set c = Nothing

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Excel.Application.EnableEvents = True
    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I think suppressing everything is helping out a little bit, but I can't tell with the `Set c = Nothing`.

There must be something that could be"refresher" or "released" to make this run the same every loop and not slow down.

Any help appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub findAndReplaceChrt()

    'Timer start
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer

    ' use & vbLF & for alt + enter

    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shpe As Shape
    Dim c As Chart

    Dim sht As Object
    Dim fndList As Variant
    Dim rplcList As Variant
    Dim listArray As Long

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Excel.Application.EnableEvents = False
    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    fndList = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
    rplcList = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")

    'Make pptPres the ppt active
    Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

    'Loop through each sld and check for chart title, grab avgScore values and create pptTable to paste into ppt chart
    For Each sld In pptPres.Slides

        'searches through shapes in the slide
        For Each shpe In sld.Shapes

            'Checks if shape is a Charts and has a Chart Title
            If Not shpe.HasChart Then GoTo nxtShpe

            Set c = shpe.Chart

            If Not c.ChartType = xlPie Then

                ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
                c.ChartData.Activate

                'Loop through each item in Array lists
                For listArray = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)

                    Worksheets(1).Cells.Replace What:=fndList(listArray), Replacement:=rplcList(listArray), _
                                                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                                                SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


                Next listArray

                c.ChartData.Workbook.Close

            End If

            Set c = Nothing     
nxtShpe:
        Next shpe

    Next sld

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Excel.Application.EnableEvents = True
    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    'End Timer
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: if your code is working and you need it streamlined, the code review may be a better fit.  Just make sure you check their FAQ before posting.

Comment: @sous2817 I've posted this on there twice. But I simplified my question here to just ask about the "releasing" part of my post

Comment: You say "by the time it reaches the 300th chart" it slows down - But are you sure that that's not just the rest of your code executing after the 300th chart is looked it? Put some `Application.StatusBar =` in there in places to see which part of your code it's exactly tripping up on.

Comment: Try this update: `Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Replace ...`

Comment: @dwirony unfortunately powerpoint doesn't support StatusBar. paul bica, this actually did speed it up a little bit, but there is still lag as the macro progressed through all the graphs. Maybe this whole thing has to do with suppressing the pop-up dialog boxes. Is there a command to clear all the dialog boxes from memory or something similar?

Comment: Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsAll and Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone are used for PowerPoint.  ppAlertsNone - No alerts or message boxes are displayed. If a macro encounters a message box, the default value is chosen and the macro continues.

Comment: @mooseman oh wow, thank you! I thought True/False was the method.